# I am not able to connect to Oracle DB via unix server in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, unix, jdbc

I have written a simple code to connect to DB

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";  
static final String DB_URL ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@unix_server_name:1521:ab";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "xyz";
static final String PASS = "xyz";

public static void main(String[] args) {
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
    System.out.println("Connection successful");
```

Whenever i run this code i get an error:

> Connecting to database... java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error:
>   The Network Adapter could not establish the connection at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:228) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at
>   PLSQL_JDBC.query_jdbc.main(query_jdbc.java:26) Caused by:
>   oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish
>   the connection

Please help me..
Thank you

Comment: Check the port, host , firewall , and also check if any other database is running

Comment: Check that the host name is correct "unix_server_name" and that the Database has this SID set-up "ab".

Comment: Replace "jdbc:oracle:thin:@unix_server_name:1521:ab" by "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//unix_server_name:1521:ab"